# FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 439, character 1) } with arb file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-localizations

I have two .arb files in my project, everything was working fine, but today I added two strings and I am receiving this error when I am doing `flutter pub get`:

```
Generating synthetic localizations package failed with 1 error:

Exception: The arb file C:\Users\KarolW\Documents\git\partyfinder-mobile\lib/l10n\app_en.arb has the following formatting issue: 
FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 439, character 1)
}
```

I tried to remove added strings, tried to remove all strings, tried to do `flutter clean`, but error is still here and I don't have idea why.

I am posting all my .arb file, I added 'from' and 'to' on the end of file:

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "appName": "Partyfinder",
  "@appName": {},
  "pageLoginMessage": "Sign in",
  "@pageLoginMessage": {},
  "facebookPageLoginMessage": "Sign in with Facebook",
  "@facebookPageLoginMessage": {},
  "email": "Email",
  "@email": {},
  "password": "Password",
  "@password": {},
  "forgotPassword": "Forgot Password?",
  "@forgotPassword": {},
  "noAccountMessage": "Don't have an account?",
  "@noAccountMessage": {},
  "register": "Sign up",
  "@register": {},
  "or": "OR",
  "@or": {},
  "enterFullName": "Please enter your full name",
  "@enterFullName": {},
  "fullName": "Full name",
  "@fullName": {},
  "enterUserName": "Please enter your username",
  "@enterUserName": {},
  "userName": "Username",
  "@userName": {},
  "enterEmail": "Please enter a valid email address",
  "@enterEmail": {},
  "enterPassword": "Please enter your password",
  "@enterPassword": {},
  "confirmPassword": "Confirm password",
  "@confirmPassword": {},
  "passwordNoMatch": "Passwords do not match",
  "@passwordNoMatch": {},
  "passwordRegEx": "Password must be at least 8 characters long",
  "@passwordRegEx": {},
  "chooseGender": "Choose your gender",
  "@chooseGender": {},
  "gender": "Gender",
  "@gender": {},
  "male": "Male",
  "@male": {},
  "female": "Female",
  "@female": {},
  "other": "Other",
  "@other": {},
  "dateOfBirth": "Date of birth",
  "@dateOfBirth": {},
  "chooseProperDate": "Please choose a proper date of birth",
  "@chooseProperDate": {},
  "city": "Where do you party?",
  "@city": {},
  "enterCity": "Please enter a proper city",
  "@enterCity": {},
  "country": "Country",
  "@country": {},
  "enterCountry": "Please enter a proper country",
  "@enterCountry": {},
  "phone": "Telephone number",
  "@phone": {},
  "enterPhone": "Please enter your telephone number",
  "@enterPhone": {},
  "haveAccount": "Already have an account?",
  "@haveAccount": {},
  "registering": "Registering",
  "@registering": {},
  "logging": "Logging",
  "@logging": {},
  "noInternet": "No internet connection, try again",
  "@noInternet": {},
  "verificationCode": "Verification code",
  "@verificationCode": {},
  "enterVerificationCodeMessage": "Please Enter 6-digit code, that we have sent to",
  "@enterVerificationCodeMessage": {},
  "noVerificationCode": "Didn't receive the code and it's not in spam?",
  "@noVerificationCode": {},
  "resendVerificationCode": "Resend",
  "@resendVerificationCode": {},
  "resendTextMessage": "Your code has been resent",
  "@resendTextMessage": {},
  "waitResendTextMessage": "You can ask for re-sending your verification code once in 15 minutes",
  "@waitResendTextMessage": {},
  "verify": "Verify",
  "@verify": {},
  "nonEmptyField": "This field cannot be empty",
  "@nonEmptyField": {},
  "emailTaken": "This email is already taken",
  "@emailTaken": {},
  "passwordReset": "Reset Password",
  "@passwordReset": {},
  "badCode": "Incorrect code",
  "@badCode": {},
  "enterEmailMessage": "Enter your email address to reset password, we will send 6 digit code to this email",
  "@enterEmailMessage": {},
  "noSuchUser": "No user with such email",
  "@noSuchUser": {},
  "sendCode": "Send code",
  "@sendCode": {},
  "enterPasswordDigitCode": "Enter the code",
  "@enterPasswordDigitCode": {},
  "incorrectCredentials": "Incorrect password",
  "@incorrectCredentials": {},
  "done": "Done",
  "@done": {},
  "clearFilter": "Clear filters",
  "@clearFilter": {},
  "filter": "Filters",
  "@filter": {},
  "clear": "Clear",
  "@clear": {},
  "location": "Location",
  "@location": {},
  "search": "Search",
  "@search": {},
  "addFriends": "Add friends",
  "@addFriends": {},
  "myFriends": "My friends",
  "@myFriends": {},
  "invites": "Invitations",
  "@invites": {},
  "suggestedFriends": "Suggested friends from Facebook",
  "@suggestedFriends": {},
  "friends": "Friends",
  "@friends": {},
  "addProfilePicture": "Add profile photo",
  "@addProfilePicture": {},
  "chosenTown": "My town",
  "@chosenTown": {},
  "follow": "Follow",
  "@follow": {},
  "typeIn": "Type in",
  "@typeIn": {},
  "distance": "Distance",
  "@distance": {},
  "date": "Date",
  "@date": {},
  "share": "Share",
  "@share": {},
  "report": "Report",
  "@report": {},
  "noFriends": "You don't have any friends",
  "@noFriends": {},
  "notFound": "Not found",
  "@notFound": {},
  "browseNoAccount": "Browse without an account",
  "@browseNoAccount": {},
  "partyspots": "PartySpots",
  "@partyspots": {},
  "events": "Events",
  "@events": {},
  "myProfile": "My Profile",
  "@myProfile": {},
  "takePhoto": "Take a photo",
  "@takePhoto": {},
  "chooseFromGallery": "Choose from gallery",
  "@chooseFromGallery": {},
  "scanQr": "Scan QR code",
  "@scanQr": {},
  "name": "First name",
  "@name": {},
  "surname": "Surname",
  "@surname": {},
  "nickName": "Nickname",
  "@nickName": {},
  "emailCheckingAvailability": "Checking whether a given e-mail address is available",
  "@emailCheckingAvailability": {},
  "nickNameCheckingAvailability": "Checking whether a given nickname is available",
  "@nickNameCheckingAvailability": {},
  "accept": "Accept",
  "@accept": {},
  "policy": "Terms of use",
  "@policy": {},
  "acceptToRegister": "Accept Terms of use in order to register.",
  "@acceptToRegister": {},
  "registerInProgress": "Registration in progress",
  "@registerInProgress": {},
  "somethingWentWrongTryInAMoment": "Something went wrong... Please try again",
  "@somethingWentWrongTryInAMoment": {},
  "registerSuccessfulVerifyEmail": "Registration is successful. Verify Your e-mail adress",
  "@registerSuccessfulVerifyEmail": {},
  "editPhoto": "Edit photo",
  "@editPhoto": {},
  "loading": "Loading",
  "@loading": {},
  "reportSentSuccessfully": "Your report has been sent successfully.",
  "@reportSentSuccessfully": {},
  "inappropriateContent": "Inappropriate content",
  "@inappropriateContent": {},
  "partySpotDoesNotExist": "PartySpot does not exist",
  "@partySpotDoesNotExist": {},
  "fakeAccount": "Fake account",
  "@fakeAccount": {},
  "impersonatingAnotherAccount": "Impersonation of another account",
  "@impersonatingAnotherAccount": {},
  "reportOther": "Other",
  "@reportOther": {},
  "description": "Description",
  "@description": {},
  "sentReport": "Send report",
  "@sentReport": {},
  "somethingWentWrong": "Something went wrong...",
  "@somethingWentWrong": {},
  "reason": "Reason",
  "@reason": {},
  "aboutUs": "About us",
  "@aboutUs": {},
  "awardRedeemedSuccessfully": "Award has been redeemed successfully.",
  "@awardRedeemedSuccessfully": {},
  "confirmAwardRedeeming": "I confirm collection of the awards",
  "@confirmAwardRedeeming": {},
  "goNearAuthorizedPersonToRedeemAward": "Approach an authorized person in order to collect the award",
  "@goNearAuthorizedPersonToRedeemAward": {},
  "notEnoughPoints": "You don't have enough points",
  "@notEnoughPoints": {},
  "redeem": "Redeem",
  "@redeem": {},
  "onlyLoggedUsersCanRedeemAwards": "Log in in order to redeem awards!",
  "@onlyLoggedUsersCanRedeemAwards": {},
  "cost": "cost",
  "@cost": {},
  "pointAbbreviation": "pt",
  "@pointAbbreviation": {},
  "thisPartySpotHasNoAwards": "That PartySpot has no awards.",
  "@thisPartySpotHasNoAwards": {},
  "more": "More...",
  "@more": {},
  "yourPoints": "Your points",
  "@yourPoints": {},
  "awards": "Awards",
  "@awards": {},
  "goBackToLoginScreen": "Go back to the Login screen",
  "@goBackToLoginScreen": {},
  "toUseThatFeatureYouHaveToBeLoggedIn": "This feature is only available for users that are logged in.",
  "@toUseThatFeatureYouHaveToBeLoggedIn": {},
  "enterName": "Enter Your first name",
  "@enterName": {},
  "enterSurname": "Enter Your surname",
  "@enterSurname": {},
  "nickNameTaken": "This nickname is already taken",
  "@nickNameTaken": {},
  "enterNickName": "Enter your nickname",
  "@enterNickName": {},
  "passwordPolicy": "The password must contain at least 8 characters, including one capital letter and one special character",
  "@passwordPolicy": {},
  "searchEnterNickName": "Enter nickname",
  "@searchEnterNickName": {},
  "isAlreadyYourFriend": "is already Your friend!",
  "@isAlreadyYourFriend": {},
  "alreadyHasYourInvitation": "already has your invitation!",
  "@alreadyHasYourInvitation": {},
  "invitedToFriends1": "Invited",
  "@invitedToFriends1": {},
  "invitedToFriends2": "to friends",
  "@invitedToFriends2": {},
  "notFoundUserNickName": "No users found with that nickname",
  "@notFoundUserNickName": {},
  "somehowItsEmptyHereUseSearchBar": "It's a little bit drafty here... Use searchbar or scan QR code in order to add friends.",
  "@somehowItsEmptyHereUseSearchBar": {},
  "nobodyIsWaitingToAddedToFriends": "Nobody is awaiting your confirmation.",
  "@nobodyIsWaitingToAddedToFriends": {},
  "yes": "Yes",
  "@yes": {},
  "no": "No",
  "@no": {},
  "removedUserFromFriends1": "Removed user",
  "@removedUserFromFriends1": {},
  "removedUserFromFriends2": "from friends",
  "@removedUserFromFriends2": {},
  "searchNotFoundEvents": "No events were found that match your search criteria",
  "@searchNotFoundEvents": {},
  "searchNotFoundPartySpots": "No PartySpots were found that match your search criteria",
  "@searchNotFoundPartySpots": {},
  "itemName": "PartySpot name",
  "@itemName": {},
  "myLocation": "My current Location",
  "@myLocation": {},
  "enterCitySearch": "Enter city",
  "@enterCitySearch": {},
  "searchNoLocation": "All",
  "@searchNoLocation": {},
  "pageCreationInProgress": "Available soon",
  "@pageCreationInProgress": {},
  "ranks": "Rankings",
  "@ranks": {},
  "badges": "Points and badges",
  "@badges": {},
  "settings": "Settings",
  "@settings": {},
  "addMeToFriends": "Add me to Your friends",
  "@addMeToFriends": {},
  "changeProfilePicture": "Change profile picture",
  "@changeProfilePicture": {},
  "profilePictureChangedSuccessfully": "Profile picture changed successfully.",
  "@profilePictureChangedSuccessfully": {},
  "pleaseWait": "Please wait",
  "@pleaseWait": {},
  "welcomeToPartySpot": "Welcome to PartySpot",
  "@welcomeToPartySpot": {},
  "weHaveConnectionIssues": "There is problem with internet connection",
  "@weHaveConnectionIssues": {},
  "cannotAddYourselfToYourFriends": "You cannot be Your own friend!",
  "@cannotAddYourselfToYourFriends": {},
  "cameraPermissionRejectedPermanently": "Camera permission has been blocked permanently, in order to use QR code scanner, go to the app settings and allow camera usage",
  "@cameraPermissionRejectedPermanently": {},
  "cameraPermissionRejected": "Camera permission is blocked",
  "@cameraPermissionRejected": {},
  "allow": "Allow",
  "@allow": {},
  "invitedUserToFriends1": "Invited",
  "@invitedUserToFriends1": {},
  "invitedUserToFriends2": "to friends",
  "@invitedUserToFriends2": {},
  "registerPage1Info": "Only your friends will see your name and surname, while others will only see your nickname. In the account settings you will be able to hide your name and surname for your friends as well.",
  "@registerPage1Info": {},
  "registerPage2Info": "We will send an activation link to the e-mail address provided. The password must contain at least 8 characters, including one capital letter and one special character.",
  "@registerPage2Info": {},
  "registerPage3Info": "Fill in these fields and we will precisely adjust the content that the application will find for you. Enter the city where you party most often and we will show you clubs and events in your area.",
  "@registerPage3Info": {},
  "advanced": "Advanced",
  "@advanced": {},
  "language": "Language",
  "@language": {},
  "theme": "Theme",
  "@theme": {},
  "loadingProfile": "Loading Profile",
  "@loadingProfile": {},
  "themeSystem": "System",
  "@themeSystem": {},
  "themeLight": "Light",
  "@themeLight": {},
  "themeDark": "Dark",
  "@themeDark": {},
  "oldPassword": "Old password",
  "@oldPassword": {},
  "pickDateOfBirth": "Pick Your date of birth",
  "@pickDateOfBirth": {},
  "updateData": "Update",
  "@updateData": {},
  "enteredWrongPassword": "Entered wrong password",
  "@enteredWrongPassword": {},
  "profileDataEditedSuccessfully": "Profile data has been updated successfully",
  "@profileDataEditedSuccessfully": {},
  "privacyPolicy": "Privacy policy",
  "@privacyPolicy": {},
  "aboutApp": "About application",
  "@aboutApp": {},
  "reportProblemWithApp": "Report problem with app",
  "@reportProblemWithApp": {},
  "logout": "Log out",
  "@logout": {},
  "reportProblem": "Report problem",
  "@reportProblem": {},
  "version": "Version",
  "@version": {},
  "versionCode": "Version code",
  "@versionCode": {},
  "loadingPolicy": "Loading Terms of use...",
  "@loadingPolicy": {},
  "loadingPrivacyPolicy": "Loading Privacy policy...",
  "@loadingPrivacyPolicy": {},
  "areYouSureToLogout": "Are You sure?",
  "@areYouSureToLogout": {},
  "tag1": "other",
  "@tag1": {},
  "tag2": "other",
  "@tag2": {},
  "tag3": "other",
  "@tag3": {},
  "gettingLocation": "Getting location",
  "@gettingLocation": {},
  "selectSuggestedCity": "Please select suggested city",
  "@selectSuggestedCity": {},
  "tryAgain": "Try again",
  "@tryAgain": {},
  "noInternetConnection": "No internet connection \n retrying...",
  "@noInternetConnection": {},
  "couldNotRestoreInternet": "Could not restore internet connection",
  "@couldNotRestoreInternet": {},
  "page": "Page",
  "@page": {},
  "shareText1": "Hey, take look at",
  "@shareText1": {},
  "shareText2PartySpot": "that PartySpot",
  "@shareText2PartySpot": {},
  "shareText2Event": "that event",
  "@shareText2Event": {},
  "couldNotGetLocation": "Could not get location... \n Please try again",
  "@couldNotGetLocation": {},
  "waitingFriends": "Sent",
  "@waitingFriends": {},
  "seemsThatClubIsNotAMemberOfPartyFinder": "Seems that, this club has not joined PartyFinder yet",
  "@seemsThatClubIsNotAMemberOfPartyFinder": {},
  "thisPartySpotNoDescription": "This PartySpot has no description...",
  "@thisPartySpotNoDescription": {},
  "thisEventNoDescription": "This event has no description...",
  "@thisEventNoDescription": {},
  "accepted": "Accepted",
  "@accepted": {},
  "generate": "Generate nick",
  "@generate": {},
  "save": "Save",
  "@save": {},
  "completeData": "Complete data",
  "@completeData": {},
  "sentInvites": "Pending",
  "@sentInvites": {},
  "enterPartySpotName": "Enter name",
  "@enterPartySpotName": {},
  "eventName": "Event name",
  "@eventName": {},
  "enterLocation": "Enter location",
  "@enterLocation": {},
  "thereIsZeroSentInvites": "Nobody is having your invitation",
  "@thereIsZeroSentInvites": {},
  "notFoundSuggestedFriends": "No suggested friends found",
  "@notFoundSuggestedFriends": {},
  "suggestedFriends": "Suggested friends",
  "@suggestedFriends": {},
  "turnOnFriendsFromFacebook": "Do you want to turn on suggesting friends from Facebook?",
  "@turnOnFriendsFromFacebook": {},
  "suggestedFriendsOff": "Suggesting friends is turned off. You can change it in settings.",
  "@suggestedFriendsOff": {},
  "doYouWantToRemove": "Do you want to remove this user",
  "@doYouWantToRemove": {},
  "doYouWantToRemoveFromFriends": "from friends?",
  "@doYouWantToRemoveFromFriends": {},
  "backToFilter": "Go to filters",
  "@backToFilter": {},
  "connectWithFacebook": "Connect",
  "@connectWithFacebook": {},
  "doYouWantToConnectWithFacebook": "Do you want to connect your account with Facebook?",
  "@doYouWantToConnectWithFacebook": {},
  "from": "From",
  "@from": {},
  "to": "To",
  "@to": {},
}
```

Comment: Got the same issue on MacOS, while the same project is working perfectly on Windows. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but can't run pub get without those errors.

Comment: @3c71 I didn't have that problem on Mac, it happened to me on Windows and accepted version helped me, that was that ```,``` on end of file.

Comment: There was some bad formatting in the translations " 0={...}, " causing issues on upgraded plugins on Mac, while ok on PC. Once fixed, everything worked as designed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be possible that the last comma needs to be removed.

Change this :

```
"from": "From",
  "@from": {},
  "to": "To",
  "@to": {},
```

To this :

```
  "from": "From",
  "@from": {},
  "to": "To",
  "@to": {}
```